# fire base in Laravel frame work and got this information from DB

Tags: php, json, laravel, object, firebase-realtime-database

I use fire base in Laravel frame work and got this information from DB

```
   array:8 [▼
  "5cR0IIftjJaGH3Zlt1SWix3HO2j2" => array:14 [▼
    "birthDay" => ""
    "bumpAvailable" => true
    "bumpLimit" => 10
    "bumpRecived" => 2
    "bumpSend" => 8
    "fact" => "Nasser ali karimi"
    "firstName" => "Nasser"
    "gender" => "male"
    "lastName" => "Karimi"
    "notification" => true
    "phoneNumber" => ""
    "photoUrl" => ""
    "socialMedia" => array:3 [▼
      "facebook" => ""
      "instagram" => ""
      "snapchat" => ""
    ]
    "uid" => "5cR0IIftjJaGH3Zlt1SWix3HO2j2"
  ]
  "8iHDZBWsn9NCIvdeG1eaLj2IBi63" => array:10 [▶]
  "A8TDVhfrBTcMIkP4qiompVtF5R82" => array:10 [▶]
  "CNqX0C7R4Jfv3kM7I1stNtR92kt2" => array:11 [▶]
  "SgsR2Xr55abGiqGu9UMgrPwFoAv1" => array:15 [▶]
  "axMw79EtZnXZq25b0taIRii8Qnl1" => array:13 [▶]
  "f7AHT2FnXiVtuzOQipAuYSBEH7f2" => array:14 [▶]
  "p2A9GEinF3de4saRKfLA5Ur510u1" => array:10 [▶]
]
```

but how I can to show each part that I want?
For example how I can show first name?
and how can I show facebook?

Comment: Do you only want information of one specific entry? Or do you want to diplay all returned entires?

Comment: I want to show first name and lastname and gender for all user once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a foreach loop to loop over all results:

```
foreach($results as $user){
  echo $user['firstName'];
  echo $user['lastName'];
  echo $user['gender'];
}
```